# ZeroMQ fails to .bind() on Docker on [0.0.0.0:5555] - address already in use. Why?

Tags: python, sockets, docker, tcp, zeromq

Got a bit problem with ZeroMQ socket on trying to **`.bind()`** on `0.0.0.0:5555` address, when tried to run it in Docker container via a Rancher Cattle.

Every time I try to run it, I'm getting the same error:

> zmq.error.ZMQError: Address already in use.

Tried to do `EXPOSE 5555` and `EXPOSE 5555/tcp` in my Dockerfile, but it did not help me.

Here is a part of my code:

```
...
self.context = zmq.Context()
self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.PUB)
self.socket.bind('tcp://%s:%d' % ('0.0.0.0', 5555))
...
```

Maybe somebody had the same problem. How to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried with other ports? What happens then?

Comment: Of course, nothing changes. I even tried to run container without this part of code and entered the shell of container. This port is unused.

Comment: what does 'netstat -nlp | grep :5555' return?

Comment: Have you tried to bind some other app to this port? Try to expose a simple hello-world webserver instead of ZMQ. Just to check if it isn't ZMQ specific.

Comment: 'netstat -nlp | grep :5555'  returns nothing at all.

Comment: I tried to run app on 0.0.0.0:5555 and it works. It's problem in 0MQ

Comment: Would you mind, Denys, to **test using "tcp://localhost:5555"** and post the results?

Comment: ZeroMQ does not allow you to make bind not to address in non ip format, so it simple will not be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After two hours of debugging i tried to make **`.bind_to_random_port()`** and noticed, that my app in Docker starts via 4 `Gunicorn` workers. So after first worker started, three another workers can not bind to the same port. Be aware of binding to only one port while you have multiple threaded or multiple workers application.

Answer (score 3):

### ZeroMQ API defines 3-ways to go:

> **Assigning a local address to a socket**
>   
>   When assigning a local address to a socket using **`zmq_bind()`** with the **`tcp://`** transport, the endpoint shall be interpreted as an interface followed by a colon and the TCP port number to use.
>   
>   An interface may be specified by either of the following:
>   
>     - The **wild-card ***, meaning all available interfaces.
>     - The **primary IPv4 address** assigned to the interface, in its numeric representation.
>     - The **interface name** as defined by the operating system.
>   
>   Interface names are **not** standardised in any way and **should be assumed to be arbitrary and platform dependent**. On Win32 platforms no short interface names exist, thus only the primary IPv4 address may be used to specify an interface.

So, at least one ought make the job progress.